# HTML How can I make one anchor change multiple framesets to different things

Tags: html, anchor, href, target, frameset

How can I make one anchor change multiple framesets to different things

```
<a href='link1' target='01'>1</a>
<a href='link2' target='02'>2</a>
<a href='link3' target='03'>3</a>
```

How to do this with only 1 anchor?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to make one single `<a>` element that targets multiple things? You can simply change the attributes with JavaScript! Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, can you please post how to do this with JS?

Comment: No problem @koumakpet!

Comment: Posted! Absolutely no problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing these with JS is extremely simple:

```
function changeTarget(element) {
    element.setAttribute("target", "02"); //Or whatever. Just use the .setAttribute method to change the attributes you want.
}
```

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!--You'll have to add something to your link though-->
<a href="link1" target="01" onclick="changeTarget(this)">1</a>
```

As always when working with JS, make sure your files are linked correctly, using the syntax below:

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

Just ask if you need clarification of anything!